# Bootstrap Spanning - Firefox vs Chrome/Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scaffolding

I have really weird spanning issues across browsers using Bootstrap.

Firefox works perfectly well and displays the spans correctly whereas Chrome/Safari spans the items the full width of the page - which I understand is a responsive behavior of Bootstrap but in my simple case, doesn't make sense.

For example, for a simple body with:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        Hello
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        Bye
    </div>
</div>
```

Firefox will display 'Hello' on one side and 'Bye' on the other.
Chrome and Safari, on the otherhand, with display 'Hello' and 'Bye' on two separate lines on top of each other.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE**

Ok so I just checked the production (deployed online) version. It works correctly in every web browser - including Chrome/Safari.

But still messed up in the local versions - what the heck?

Comment: I can see  the span are aligned to each other. http://jsbin.com/gekorobe/1 . It might be a a cache problem.

Comment: I've tried running in in-cognito mode as well. But I get the same result.

Comment: Thats really strange issue, the DEMO I produced here have same results on all browser. CSS version is same on deployed version as in your local?

Comment: or may be you can use CSS version, might be your local site is correct and deployed version picking from cache.

Comment: You have up-to-date versions you are using on your local host, right?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about bootstrap but it seems like Chrome and Safari are recognizing those divs as display:block, and firefox display:inline-block.

Can you add inline style to test or even edit in Chrome's inspect element?  Ex:

```
<div class="span6" style="display:inline-block;">
    hello
</div>
<div class="span6" style="display:inline-block;">
    bye
</div>
```